# Измение разметки из-за поля @+id/ в preview AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Читал книгу по Android-разработке и наткнулся на такой странный феномен... У меня есть разметка: `Spinner`, `Button` и `TextView` в горизонтальной `LinearLayout`. Проблема в том, что когда у `Spinner` имеется `id`, он занимает все поле, а когда нет — помещается кнопка с текстом. Объясните, почему так происходит? Проблема именно в предпросмоторщике (да, Юрий, я знаю, что он глючный :)). Вот разметки и фото:

Разметка номер 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/beer_colors" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/find_beer"
        android:id="@+id/find_beer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Something"
        android:id="@+id/brands" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка номер 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        android:entries="@array/beer_colors" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/find_beer"
        android:id="@+id/find_beer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Something"
        android:id="@+id/brands" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Фото: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм... А если в `dp` ширину спинеру проставить?.. Ну ещё можно, наверное, поменять уровень API предпросмоторщика...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если в `dp` — все нормально, а отображается так на всех версиях.

Comment: Ну, если такое поведение верно только для спинера, то модно считать это одной из баг превьюера) И не пользоваться им)))

Answer (score 2):

> Символ плюса (+) обозначает, что это имя нового ресурса, который
>   необходимо создать и добавить к нашим ресурсам (в файле R.java)

Это не просто присваивание идентификатора(хотя по логике так и есть), получается что в вашем случае, когда вы удаляете строчку с id spinner у него пропадает макет - [Макеты](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)  Так будет с любыми view widgets, наглядно будет видно со списком к примеру ListView.

Элементы которые находятся ниже становятся видимыми, а spinner в viewer, исчезнет или свернется. Вот только откуда слово ligth? видимо было с другой разметки.

Comment: Стоп. Тогда почему, если я ставлю `id` (кнопку с текстом не должно быть видно), на реальном устройстве все работает, как задумано? На телефоне `id` выполняет, на сколько я понял, только функцию `id`. А `light` — это первый элемент массива (`android:enteries`).

Comment: потому что это linear_layout и спинер занимает все место выталкивая элементы, получается вправо(могу ошибваться) поставьте у спинера размеры 100x100 к примеру для наглядности.

Comment: Это я понял и с жесткими размерами все работает, но почему без размеров в превью и на телефоне по разному отображается (в превью выталкивает, а на телефоне — нет)? Это баг превьюера или что-то другое?